# Azure VM Restore snapshot to same AD

Tags: active-directory, azure

I need to restore a Azure VM snapshot backup of a VM and keep them both in the same AD. The DC is on the same subnet also in Azure.

When restoring, the windows computername on the restored server will be exactly the same as the old one, that will cause some DNS-issues in the AD. So I need to rename the new one after the restore.

**Now how do I do that without touching the old server and its AD object / DNS entry?** The server is part of a Windows virtual desktop environment so I do not want to rejoin it to the domain.

By changing the restored servers computername in windows settings, will that also trigger a rename on the AD object?

If I remove the restored server from the domain, will that keep or delete the AD object on the DC of the old server?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with restore without nic or IP and do sysprep

See here:
[How to clone, disjoin & rename a Windows 2008 R2 VM offline, then rejoin domain online](https://serverfault.com/questions/653464/how-to-clone-disjoin-rename-a-windows-2008-r2-vm-offline-then-rejoin-domain)